# Where is the remote that my working copy was pulled from?

Tags: svn

I'm working on an svn repository and there appears to be multiple working copies (all of which are outdated to the master) on the same server. I want to pull a working copy, but I don't know which one is the actual repository (the directory I was given does not exist).

In one of the working copies, is there a way to see where it was pulled from? Similar to the `git remote` command. (I'm coming from git).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`svn info`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.info.html) in your working copy.  It will output something like the following:

```
> svn info
Path: .
Working Copy Root Path: C:\your_working_copy
URL: https://your.server.com/svn/project/trunk
Relative URL: ^/trunk
Repository Root: https://your.server.com/svn/project
Repository UUID: 2a590eaa-b7ce-4e9b-8fc4-5871439b179a
Revision: 14266
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: pquirk
Last Changed Rev: 14266
Last Changed Date: 2017-05-24 10:30:21 -0400 (Wed, 24 May 2017)
```

The URL and Repository Root fields contain where it was pulled from.

Comment: This worked, but I had to update my working copy, thanks!